# Word for things come easily to me so I don't try?

Tags: adjectives

I don't want to say I am lazy, because that's not the closest match. 
I am not apathetic, because I do care. 
Does anyone know the word to describe not trying hard because things come easily...?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you are **coasting**.

> (of a person or vehicle) move easily without using power.

Often a person who is a **natural** at something is described as coasting.

Other similar terms:

- sailing
- cruising

Comment: If I am coasting then I am a _____

Comment: coast: proceed with little or no effort

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, because there's no need for you to work hard to get the answer.  You aren't lazy.  As RyeBread said "a natural" is one term.  You could also say you're unchallenged or 'not challenged' with the work at hand.
I've seen this happen with bright kids in elementary school: they can just see the answer to, say, the arithmetic problems and so there is no "work" to "show your work."  Clearly they aren't lazy; they're just far ahead of the level of the curriculum.